# Is there a way to raise an event in a xaml user control's viewmodel that can be consumed by the user control's parent viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a combobox in a user control that has it's own view model.  When the user changes the selected item,  a property in the view model is changed,  but I want to raise an event from the view model to tell the usercontrol's container that the user has selected something and pass the string selected.

```
<UserControl x:Class= ....etc>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <viewmodel:PortsViewModel x:Key="pvm"></viewmodel:PortsViewModel>
    </UserControl.Resources>
        <Menu DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource pvm}}">
        <ComboBox Name="PortsCombo" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ports}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SPort}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="PortName">
        </ComboBox>
    </Menu>
</UserControl>`
```

and in the window (what to add to the xaml?:

```
<localviews:PortsView />
```

and my viewmodel:

```
public Port SPort
{
    get { return _sport; }
    set
    {
        var portName = value.PortName;
        int portNo = value.PortNo;

        _sport = value;

        // What to add here to trigger the event?
    }
}
```

Comment: A UserControl should not have an own view model at all. It should instead expose bindable properties (i.e. dependency properties) that are bound to properties of the view model of the Window or Page in which it is used. If it has its own, private view model it is effectively isolated from the application's view model.

Comment: If you are using MVVM Light, you can use a message to trigger work on another class. That way neither model needs to have any relationship.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using .net core 3,  and afaict, MVVM light doesn't support Core 3 yet.

Comment: @Clemens,  While researching,  I saw lots of examples where user controls had view models, Thus, it seemed to me to be the way to go.  Can you explain why it shouldn't be done?  I want to avoid having to have everything in my main view model.

Comment: For the exact reason that I already mentioned. Your control's view model is isolated from the rest of the view model structure of your application. All those examples on the internet that show UserControls with own view models are plain wrong, and IMO written by people that have no idea what they are talking about. If you take a look at the controls in the framework or third party libraries, is there any with an own view model?

Comment: So just make `Ports` and `SPort` (or better `SelectedPort`) dependency properties of the control, and bind them to a view model that is provided by the parent element, e.g. the Window or Page. Thus you would already have your notification in the "parent view model".

Comment: In the UserControl's XAML use them like `ItemsSource="{Binding Ports, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`